# Azure Front Door cannot load balance OAUTH authenticated azure functions?

Tags: azure-front-door

I am trying to load balance several azure functions HTTP triggers using FrontDoor, but I am having issues with the health probes.

Our functions use OAUTH auth and thus all probes fail.

I have tried adding the warmup_path env pointing to healthprobe.html but the function seems to have hardcoced URL to add /api/healthprobe.html so I cannot get the probes to answer properly on that URL since the healthprobe URL is not configurable in front door

Comment: Is there a reason you can't change your application code to _not_ require OAuth for that particular URI?

Comment: @Dai we don’t handle OAUTH in the code we handle it in the function app, but I figured it out how to change the api url for healthprpbe in the front doors

Comment: @MattDouhan can you also tell me how you did that ??